# FindResource PNG fails?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am trying to use FindResource to get a handle to a PNG in my .rc file, but it always fails with 1814 - name not found. PNG is certainly in the .rc, its line is:

```
IDB_PNG1                PNG                     "Resources\\116.png"
```

And I am trying to load it using

```
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), TEXT("IDB_PNG1"), TEXT("PNG"));
```

but it always gives a NULL.

Any ideas?

Thanks..

Comment: Not exactly an answer but try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. This is the recommended way of dealing with image resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FindResource(.., TEXT("IDB_PNG1"), ...);
```

That's wrong, the ID is a number, not a string.  Use MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1).

Answer (score 0):

FindResourceEx had to be used and Neutral language explicitly set.